# Fill Nan with all the information from previous week

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
    Week  Store End Cap       UPC
0      1      1       A  123456.0
1      1      1       B  789456.0
2      1      1       B  546879.0
3      1      1       C  423156.0
4      1      2       A  231567.0
5      1      2       B  456123.0
6      1      2       D  689741.0
7      2      1       A  321654.0
8      2      1       B       NaN
9      2      1       C  852634.0
```

I want for every row where I have a Nan UPC to go and check the previous week, match on Store and End Cap and then grab **all** the information from previous week where we are matching.

So in the above example (2/1/B) would match with both the second and third row that show (1/1/B) and the desired output would look like this:

```
       Week  Store End Cap       UPC
    0      1      1       A  123456.0
    1      1      1       B  789456.0
    2      1      1       B  546879.0
    3      1      1       C  423156.0
    4      1      2       A  231567.0
    5      1      2       B  456123.0
    6      1      2       D  689741.0
    7      2      1       A  321654.0
    8      2      1       B  789456.0
    9      2      1       B  546879.0
   10      2      1       C  852634.0
```

We now have **both** 789456 and 546879 show up for (2/1/B)

How can I go around doing this?

I tried sorting and forward filling but that only gets me 1 of the values not all.

Comment: @QuangHoang this did not work as it only filled the Nan with one of the values. I need both 789456 and 546879 to be different rows for week 2 store 1 end cap B. This code only gave me 546879 without 789456.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try self merge after assigning +1 to week

```
out = df.merge(df.assign(Week=df['Week'].add(1)),
on=['Week','Store','End Cap'],how='left',suffixes=('','_y'))

out['UPC'] = out['UPC'].fillna(out['UPC_y'])
out = out.loc[:, df.columns]
```

---

```
print(out)

    Week  Store End Cap       UPC
0      1      1       A  123456.0
1      1      1       B  789456.0
2      1      1       B  546879.0
3      1      1       C  423156.0
4      1      2       A  231567.0
5      1      2       B  456123.0
6      1      2       D  689741.0
7      2      1       A  321654.0
8      2      1       B  789456.0
9      2      1       B  546879.0
10     2      1       C  852634.0
```

Comment: Hi @anky 

The solution you provided has 1 flaw. It is true that you were able to get the 2 items on End Cap B for Week 2 store 1.

That being said you also changed index 7 from UPC 321654 to 123456 and index 9 from 852634 to 423156 which shouldn't happen.

Thanks!

Comment: @etuo I edited the answer , please try now..?

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked perfectly. I will try it under a few different scenarios but I think it will hold. Selected your answer as best!